# Alpha Interfering With Smooth Color Spectrum - Processing

Tags: colors, processing

I am trying to create a color spectrum that fades in from the start of a sketch. To do this I simply set colorMode(HSB, 255) and then draw lines with stroke(map(x, 0, width, 0, 255), 255, 255, 5), and no background clearing. The alpha of 5 builds on itself and eventually creates a solid spectrum. However the spectrum is broken up into blocks of color, not a smooth transition. I tested the program without the alpha and it makes a smooth spectrum, so it is because of the alpha value.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Full code:

```java
void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  colorMode(HSB, 255);
}
void draw(){
  for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
    stroke(map(x, 0, width, 0, 255), 255, 255, 5);
    line(x,0,x,height);
  }
}
```

Picture of output: [image: unwanted output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're drawing transparency on top of transparency on top of transparency.

This doesn't have the effect of drawing the target color darker and darker. It has the effect of converging onto a solid color. I'm having trouble explaining that: the transparent colors are **added**, so multiple values will converge on the same color.

The point is: instead of drawing transparency on top of transparency, you should call the `background()` function to clear out the old colors and then redraw the colors with an increasing alpha value. Here's an example:

```java
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  colorMode(HSB, 255);

}
void draw() {

  float alpha = constrain(frameCount, 0, 255);

  background(200);

  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    stroke(map(x, 0, width, 0, 255), 255, 255, alpha);
    line(x, 0, x, height);
  }  
}
```

[image: color spectrum]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I understand what's happening now!

Comment: @SorenLantz No problem. This was an interesting question. Definitely had me scratching my head for a few minutes!